# How to upload to a user folder in s3 with the user's SUB and using the Java SDK in a Lambda

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-java-sdk

I have a React front end using Amplify and Cognito and a Java backend. In React the user can sign in and then call "Storage.put" and the file is saved to the user's private folder. In the Java backend, I want to get a user using [AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) and then save a file to their user folder without a login. The problem is in the Java backend I don't know how to do it except concatenate the path i.e. /private/{user_sub}. Is there any way to use the same mechanism Amplify does where I just pass in the SUB as a parameter to the AmazonS3 client and have it put the file in the user's folder without any manual intervention?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit unclear.  Does each user have their own S3 bucket?  Or are you just trying to create a new folder within the S3 bucket?

Comment: @stdunbar there is only one bucket and each user would have their own folder...so the latter.

Comment: I think the best way is to have a unique s3Key for each user with the userKey and userPoolId in the key path.